# Updating an activity that has not been opened

Tags: android, android-activity, view, screen, background-process

What would be the best method for updating the information on an activity that hasnt been opened by the user yet?
 For example say I have three activities; A, B, and C. Lets say I want to open the application and press a button on activity A that changes the information displayed on activity B and C without having to open B and C first. I know that doing this would crash the application because the variables being changed on B and C would yet to be declared and initialized, I know that one way around this would be to start the app by first openening C which then opens B and then A, starting all three activities but this seems messy. 
 Is there a way to transparently open/start B and C without jumping around to different activities when the app is launched?
 Thanks

Comment: Why do you need it? It sounds like you're doing something wrong. Maybe you need to use `Service` instead?

Comment: Object Oriented Programming - Message passing. <~~ Google keywords. Getters and setters, intent.put, shared preferences, files, synchronization, static keyword, Anything can do!

Comment: You need to pass the data you want to be changed to your activities and have them display whatever you data you pass

Comment: @Foxinsocks I need information to be updated on more than one activity but I am not expecting the user to open the actitivty straight away and therefore ant information added to the second activity would crash the application if it hasnt been started

Comment: @MahmoudElmorabea are you suggesting opening/starting the other activities on the change of the data?

Comment: @CameronB just do it when `onResume` method is called. `Activity` is a visual component so it should work only when it's visible.

Comment: @CameronB, instead of changing the variables of the B and C activities immediately when the data changes .. send those changes to the activities through intent and display the new data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your B and C Activities from a persistent Storage made by A, for example, use SharedPreferences to store the data you need to have updated, and use it too in B and C to load the previously stored data.

The SharedPreferences works with key/value data, wich is useful in the whole context of the app, it also accepts Strings, ints, and almost whatever you need.

As a mini template:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("name_of_your_preferences_store", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

...

public boolean setActualData(String data){

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("my_tag_for_specific_data_field", data);
        return editor.commit();
    }

public String getActualData(){

            return prefs.getString("my_tag_for_specific_data", "data_defeult_return_value");

        }
```

Comment: So you're saying store all of the data to be changed on B and C within A until the user opens B and C? and then when B and C are started, have them grab the data from A and fill in the gaps on B and C?

Comment: Not exactly, using SharedPreferences you would be storing that data outside of A, in a preferences file wich is available from A,B and C.
The only con I would tell is that if you need to save huge (really huge) amounts of data maybe you should find another way, but some crazy things may be done with SharedPreferences, and works for average data global storing.

Comment: ah ok so all infomation for A, B and C is stored outside of the activities and then the data for each activity is grabbed when it is needed

Comment: you got it, also I'd forget to say that if you want, you are able to save whole serializable Java objects and get them as any other type, just usin a type cast.

Comment: Cool, great idea!! I could have a thread running on each activity thats constantly updating the UI and changing it depending on the data stored outside of the activities

Comment: I really don't know wich is your final objective with this app structure, but maybe you won't need to make any continuus thread, because if you get the data while in B o C, you are pretty sure that A is not updating that data (Activities in background automatically stops), so just covering the Activities LifeCycle would be enough: Save the data in the onPause method of A, and then in the onCreate or onResume of B or C, just get the data and put it into the UI, so you won't have to update continuosly. Just as a final thought ^^

Answer (score 1):

Message Passing In Java

- When a thread sends a message (an object) to another thread.
- Used for thread communication and synchronization in environments where the threads do not have shared memory Hence the threads cannot share semaphores or monitors and cannot use shared variables to communicate. Message passing can still be used, of course, in a shared memory platform.
- Messages are sent through a channel with an operation like send(channel, message) and received from a channel with an operation like receive(channel, message). Messages can be passed synchronously, meaning the sender blocks until the received does a receive and the receiver blocks until the sender does a send. Since the sender and receiver are at specific known points in their code at a known specific instant of time, synchronous message passing is also called a simple rendezvous with a one-way flow of information from the sender to the receiver. An example is a chess game agent. The agents can process messages synchronously, since they'll be handshaking throughout the entire game.

#### - In asynchronous message passing, the sender does not block. If there is not a receiver waiting to receive the message, the message is queued or buffered. The receiver still blocks if there is no queued or buffered message when a receive is executed.

```
class A{

    public static void main(){
        B objB = new B(); 
        objB.setValue(3); 

    }


}



class B{
    static int value; 
    public void setValue(int valueFromAnotherClass){
        value = valueFromAnotherClass; 

    }

}
```